# Are there any OK image recognition libraries for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, image, image-recognition

I want to be able to compare an image taken from a webcam to an image stored on my computer.

The library doesn't need to be one hundred percent accurate as it won't be used in anything mission critical (e.g. police investigation), I just want something OK I can work with.

I have tried a demonstration project for [Image Recognition from CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/BackPropagationNeuralNet.aspx), and it only works with small images / doesn't work at all when I compare an exact same image 120x90 pixels (this is not classified as OK :P ).

Has there been any success with image recognition before?

If so, would you be able to provide a link to a library I could use in either C# or VB.NET?

Comment: It definately works with much larger images than this, must be some other problem possibly the format.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You could try this: http://code.google.com/p/aforge/

It includes a comparison analysis that will give you a score. There are many other great imaging features of all types included as well.

```
// The class also can be used to get similarity level between two image of the same size, which can be useful to get information about how different/similar are images:
// Create template matching algorithm's instance

// Use zero similarity to make sure algorithm will provide anything
ExhaustiveTemplateMatching tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0);

// Compare two images
TemplateMatch[] matchings = tm.ProcessImage( image1, image2 );

// Check similarity level
if (matchings[0].Similarity > 0.95)
{
    // Do something with quite similar images
}
```

Comment: Sounds great! Lets hope it works as expected... I'll mark your answer as accepted if it does. :)

Comment: It works absolutely fantastic! 

100% similar for comparing its own image, 91% similar for me sitting upright on my chair and me leaning to my left. 

This is everything I could have hoped for, thanks a billion :)

Comment: Thats awesome, i am glad i could link you to it. I wish somehow there was a way to payback the guy who linked to me first. It was exactly what i needed in one of my projects as well. Thanks

Comment: You can always trust Stackoverflow for your hard questions! Done a lot of googling without finding any good libs. Thanks

Comment: Okay i always had the idea of implementing my hypothetical application using image recognition.. now i could get ma hands dirty! thanks mattlant! ;)

Comment: @mattlant which dll should be added as a reference and included using header for this comparison ?

Comment: i searched for a long time, but this answer is PERFECT

Comment: This answer is great, but is does pixel matching which can be taxing on a large set of images. Is there a better method that can create a "signature" of an image ahead of time, store that signature in a database, and then match against that instead so there is less overhead at comparison time?

Answer (score 10):

You can exactly use [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) for .NET.

Answer (score 4):

I did it simply. Just download the EyeOpen library [here](http://similarimagesfinder.codeplex.com/).
Then use it in your C# class and write this:

```
 use eyeopen.imaging.processing
```

Write

```
ComparableImage cc;

ComparableImage pc;

int sim;

void compare(object sender, EventArgs e){

    pc = new ComparableImage(new FileInfo(files));

    cc = new ComparableImage(new FileInfo(file));

    pc.CalculateSimilarity(cc);

    sim = pc.CalculateSimilarity(cc);

    int sim2 = sim*100

    Messagebox.show(sim2 + "% similar");
}
```

Comment: Simple and easy image comparison, I like it.

Comment: @j0k, I guess because the answer works for 2 questions, as demonstrated by the upvotes....