# How do I use .NET to find an orange ball in an image?

Tags: c#, image-processing, arduino

I'm  getting images from a C328R camera attached to a small arduino robot. I want the robot to drive towards orange ping-pong balls and pick them up. I'm using the C# code supplied by  funkotron76 at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/C328R.aspx.

Is there a library I can use to do this, or do I need to iterate over every pixel in the image looking for orange? If so, what kind of tolerance would I need to compensate for various lighting conditions?

I could probably test to figure out these numbers, but I'm hoping someone out there knows the answers.

Comment: There's a previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152028/are-there-any-ok-image-recognition-libraries-for-net) that addresses good image recognition libraries for .NET.

Comment: interesting project! Are you using the same hardware or just the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vision can be surprisingly difficult, especially as you try to tolerate varying conditions.  A few good things to research include Blob Finding (searching for contiguous pixels matching certain criteria, usually a threshold of brightness), [Image Segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_%28image_processing%29) (can you have multiple balls in an image?) and general theory on [Hue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue) (most vision algorithms work with grayscale or binary images, so you'll first need to transform the image in a way that highlights the orangeness as the criteria for selection.)

Since you are presumably tracking these objects in real time as you move toward them, you might also be interested in learning about tracking models, such as the [Kalman filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter).  It's overkill for what you're doing, but it's interesting and the basic ideas are helpful.  Since you presumably know that the object should not be moving very quickly, you can use that fact to filter out false positives that could otherwise lead you to move away from the object.  You can put together a simpler version of this kind of filtering by simply ignoring frames that have moved too far from the previous accepted frame (with a few  boundary conditions to avoid getting stuck ignoring the object.)