# learning how to do basic image processing

Tags: c#

what are the best tools for c# to do image processing? i am a beginner and want to learn the basics

Comment: First of all, you must have a specific goal in mind ... what is it? What are you trying to build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting started with this:

http://code.google.com/p/aforge/

(Source: [Are there any OK image recognition libraries for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152028/are-there-any-ok-image-recognition-libraries-for-net))

Once you learn the basics, you can try writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

Try Emgu CV, it is the wrapper of opencv in .net. And you can get more information about it from :
http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=opencv+c%23

Answer (score 0):

Also check the [Image Processing Lab](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Image_Processing_Lab.aspx) sample in C#, which uses AForge.NET library.