# Recogize a rectangle of certain dimensions in an image using .NET

Tags: .net, image-processing, image-recognition

I would like to recognize the outline of a black rectangle on a white background using any 'ok' library for .NET.

I am aware of this question:

[Are there any OK image recognition libraries for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152028/are-there-any-ok-image-recognition-libraries-for-net)

I would just like a little more of a trail head into image recognition libraries and how to use them in this specific case.

My ideal solution would take the form of:

Given two images; a real image and a control image, of just a black rectangle outline on a white background, return everything in the real image inside of the black rectangle on the real image.

It can be assumed that the real image would have a black rectangle outline matching the general size and a general location (but not exact) of the control image. And outside of the rectangle on the real image should be generally white-ish, similar to the control image. Any image could be inside the black rectangle however.

C# Source code would be preferred. I'll accept something that will only recognize an exact image as long as the library has some fuzzy-type functions I can play with to refine it and am shown in their general direction.

Comment: Stated differently, given an image, you would like to detect a rectangle of a pre-defined size. correct ? (once you have the rectangle detected, identifying points inside it is trivial)

Comment: Correct, the size would be variable, but within a reasonable finite range. So for example, find a rectangle that is 12x100 in size, it would say a trapezoid of 12X99(L1),89(L2) is one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any pre-made packages, but there are a couple of algorithms made for this

If the size and shape of the object in the image won't vary too much from a set template (i.e. each time you run the algorithm, you know pretty well what the shape looks like, including size), then template matching (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching) is by far the easiest solution

However if the size and shape could be a bit more variable, then you'll want to look at the Hough transform (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform)